# modify pbit data source in a program

Tags: java, powerbi, zip

I am trying to modify a pbit archive in java in my application.

The point is to update the data source of a pbit without using any PowerBI application so I have to modify the DataModelSchema entry.

My problem is : when I read the file with an InputStream and display it in the console, there are blank spaces added between each letter so I am not able to search and replace the right string. Even if I add artificially blank spaces in my string.

For example if i search "content" or even "c o n t e n t", it never finds it.

That problem never appears when I read "normal" .zip archives.

An overview of my ouput when i read the file with additional blank spaces :
https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Service/modify-pbit-data-source-in-a-program/m-p/1744747#M124339

So I would like to get to know if there is a special encoding in pbit templates which might add special spaces or whatever if there is a way to read it properly.

Thanks for your help,

Regards

J.MARQUE

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify if someone get the same problem: that appears that it is not possible (for now) to update directly the content of the data schema of a pbit template, the only way seems to use Power BI REST API.

Answer (score 1):

DataModelSchema (at least the PBIT I am looking at right now to solve this problem myself) is encoded in UTF-16 LE, which uses 2 bytes per character.  Because it is little-endian, for probably the majority of the text content, the first byte of each character is typically the same as the ASCII byte for a character and the second byte is very often 0x00.

If whatever tool you are looking at it with is not interpreting multiple bytes per character properly, it probably looks to your editor like spaces in between ASCII characters, but it's really a lot of 0x00 high bytes on every character.

If you open the file in Visual Studio Code, it should auto-detect it as UTF-16 LE (it doesn't seem to have the byte order mark it should probably have at the beginning, to tell you it is little-endian - because the default is supposed to be big-endian `<sigh/>`)

I have now completed this effort, and so I can lay out the general process for you (which I eventually completed in Powershell):

Unzip the PBIT file, including all folders

In DataModelSchema, you will have things like Source - Sql.Database() - these are what need to be changed.  This is a UTF16-LE JSON file with no BOM, and no trailing CRLF, so that's a little fiddly if you want to stick to exactly how the DataModelSchema is written when you write out the changed file.

Rezip all files, including the folder structure.  The other things I discovered is that the Powershell Compress-Archive doesn't seem to make zip files that PowerBI likes, even though the exact same files zipped with 7zip or Windows "Send to compressed folder" are fine.  I moved to using Compress-7zip